# WARNING: Compat.UTF8String is deprecated, use String instead

Tags: julia

I get the following error message while reading strings. How could I overcome it or set it quient? Julia 0.6.

WARNING: Compat.UTF8String is deprecated, use String instead.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you show your source code please?  Also, which version of Julia are you using?

Comment: UTF8String was deprecated in 0.5, not 0.6. Actively maintained packages have all caught up by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable deprecation warnings by launching julia with the `--depwarn=no` option.

Comment: Or fix the code not to use UTF8String. This is a fairly simple search-and-replace: `s/UTF8String/String/g`. Unless you're doing something complicated.